# J2000 to WGS84 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84

How do I transform [Earth-Centered Inertial J2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered_inertial#J2000) CRS to WGS84 CRS in QGIS?

I searched J2000 in [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/),
however nothing found. I don't know the proj4 string of J2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS is not designed to handle J2000 data. Your data would have 4 coordinates (X,Y,Z and time), while QGIS only handles 2-dimensional coordinates (long and lat or X and Y).

It is possible to reproject coordinates with cs2cs if you set the prime meridian according to the time. Every hour from 12 UTC is a shift of 15° to the greenwich meridian:

put `7 51` in a test file `in.txt` and run the following commands:

```
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +proj=geocent <in.txt >geocent.txt
cs2cs +proj=geocent +to +proj=latlong +pm=0 <geocent.txt >geocentout.txt
cs2cs +proj=geocent +to +proj=latlong +pm=15 <geocent.txt >>geocentout.txt
```

The geocentered coordinates are

```
3992051.06  490162.24 4933544.62
```

and the reprojection returns:

```
7dE 51dN 0.003
8dW 51dN 0.003
```